# Center content in longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have this table

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{6cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
\hline
Blub & Bla & Blip & Blop \\
Blub & Bla & Blip & Blop \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now, for whatever reason, I would like to center ONE cell of the second column.
How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using a `p`aragraph column type (with fixed length), you can issue `\centering` inside the cell to centre it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{6cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
\hline
Blub & Bla & Blip & Blop \\
Blub & \centering Bla & Blip & Blop \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Other column types (like `l` and `r`) requires a different approach.

Comment: Wow... I bet I tried that before... oh well. Thanks!

Comment: With the caveat that if the *last* column is involved, either one says `\centering\arraybackslash` or ends the cell by `\tabularnewline`.

Comment: I had to add a `\par` to close the centering to make this work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach -- which works regardless of whether the column is specified via `l`, `r`, or `p` monikers -- is to use the `\multicolumn` command. This command takes three arguments: set `1` as the first argument (the number of columns), `c` as the second argument (to center it, in this case), and "Bla" (or whatever it may be...) as the third argument:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Bla}
```

Comment: \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Bla} worked for me

Comment: Does not work in the top row

Comment: @AFog - `\multicolumn` works in *any* row, including the very first row. Please clarify what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: The specified column width was ignored when I used \multicolumn in the first row.

Comment: @AFog - Not sure I understand what you are trying to say. For sure, the `c` column type, which LaTeX is told to use by the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Bla}` directive, does *not* have a "prespecified column width". Hence, there is no prespecified column width to ignore to begin with. However, that doesn't mean that `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Bla}` "does not work." Please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying to center text in a table. I am using the p column type in order to specify column width.

Comment: @AFog - You shoould check out the `w` column type, then, to set up columns with pre-specified widths. Type  `texdoc array` at a command prompt to bring up the user guide of the `array` package and learn more about the `w` column type.